# Can i send intent broadcast from a web browser in the phone that can be received by interested broadcast receivers(native apps)?

Tags: android

Can i send intent broadcast from a web browser in the phone that can be received by interested broadcast receivers(native apps) in Android ?

Comment: Are you talking about a website or an app that uses web technology such as phonegab ?

Comment: from a mobile browser to an Android App in that phone

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use this inside the HTML:

```
<a href="intent://my_host#Intent;scheme=my_scheme;action=my_action;end">Link to my stuff</a>
```

Then put these in the manifest:

```
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        <data android:scheme="my_scheme" android:host="my_host" />
    </intent-filter>
```

Comment: Can we send a broadcast like below from html?

Comment: Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.setAction("de.vogella.android.mybroadcast");
sendBroadcast(intent);

Comment: Sibish : HTML code where you write in website button click or application button click ?

Comment: Uriel Frankel : can you explian me detail in myhpst and myscema what should i wrote on that and in html code how can i write ?

Comment: myhost is the package name in the AndroidManifest. the scheme can be neglect. I use the scheme my_scheme:// in my app. if you dont, do not use it